# Overriding ActionBarCompat overflow pop-up background?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am using actionbarcompat for my android project and using `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as my base Theme.The overflow menu in this action bar has a black background by default which I want to change to white color.I know this can be done overdding the `popup widget` with property `popupBackground` but its not working in my case.My styles file has following code:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyActionBarDropDown</item>
         <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
        <item name="popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
</style>
```

But the above code is not running as its giving me **Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'popupBackground'**.SomeOne please help me to correct above code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ->

```
<item name="popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
```

Put it like this ->

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Its not working in any API version.Its still showing the black background